# Unity is not responding to mouse clicks

Tags: unity, mouse

I am using Ubuntu for 5 weeks now.
Last night Ubuntu did not respond to mouse clicks. But movement works just fine.

I thought this was because off my wireless mouse. So i plugged in a mouse with an usb-cable. Same problem.

I have a standard installation of 12.04LTS.

I think the problem occured some time (not immidately ) after latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

Open Software -center

search and install

> pointing devices

Launch and customize your settings.

Comment: How can I do this Pulkit609?
I could only click the system icon at the right top.
After this, I could go to System settings and via Change Mouse and Trackpad, I could change some parameters. I saw a happy face when I double-clicked, but could not click anywhere else!
Even closing a windows did not work.
I had to force a shutdown with the powerbutton and switch back to Windows to respond :-(

Comment: After installing 13.04, I had the same problem.

Comment: After installing 13.04, I had the same problem.
However, I noticed that when I leave the wireless mouse in the loading-dock, everything works fine.
When I take the wireless mouse, it looks to work fine, but again unity does not respond. Even the wired mouse gives the same problem!
Everything worked fine until yesterday. I have also tested the wireless mouse in Windows 7. No problem.
I have installed the recommended software for pointing devices. No result however.

Another thing is that Firefox is now installed in English, everything else in Dutch.
However, this I will put in a new topic.